# Go looks for packages in wrong directory

Tags: go

I've used the [Windows msi](https://golang.org/dl/) to install Go on my machine, but when I try to run a trivial `Hello World`, like so:

```
go run hello.go
```

I get the following error:

> hello.go:3:8: cannot find package "fmt" in any of:
>           C:\Go\src\pkg\fmt (from $GOROOT)

In the `GOROOT` this package can indeed not be found, since it's installed in the following directory:

```
C:\Go\src (missing the \pkg)
```

`GOROOT` is set to `C:\Go` (automatically), `C\Go\bin` is added to the `PATH`

My `GOPATH` is set to my workspace, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

How can this be fixed? Should I copy all packages to `C:\Go\src\pkg`?
Did I do anything wrong?

**EDIT**

As requested by @Volker, here's the output of `go env`:

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCHAR=6
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=D:\aage\gocode
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
```

Comment: Are you sure `GOROOT` is set to `C:\Go`, and not to `C:\Go\src`?

Comment: Post the output of `go env`.

Comment: @VonC Yes, double checked just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `%PATH%`: I have multiple go versions installed and I see:

- `fmt` in `%GOROOT%(1.3)\src\pkg`: `C:\prgs\go\go1.3.2.windows-amd64\src\pkg\fmt\`
- `fmt` in `%GOROOT%(1.4)\src`: `C:\prgs\go\go1.4.windows-amd64\src\fmt\`

The sources have been reorganized.
See "[Go 1.4 `src/pkg → src`](http://golang.org/s/go14nopkg)".

That means you might see that error if you are trying to compile with a go 1.3 while `GOROOT` points to a Go1.4 installation.

If that doesn't work, uninstall, and use the [`go1.4.windows-amd64.zip`](https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.4.windows-amd64.zip) archive: unzip it anywhere you want, point `GOROOT` to it, add `GOROOT/bin` and everything should work.

Comment: Or maybe you had a go 1.3 and you have overridden it with a go1.4 installation?

Comment: Nice answer. For anyone using vim-go that is getting this error: you need to run `:GoUpdateBinaries` so that your tooling is compatible with Go 1.4.